# Why do my garage door opener remotes need to be reset frequently?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

The remote for my garage door opener needs to be reset frequently.  I have two different remotes and they both need to be reset frequently so the problem seems to be with the garage door opener.  Is there something I can do to fix this problem?  Can I replace just a circuit board or something?  It's a pain to reset the remotes once a week or so. Does anyone know what causes this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the brand and model #?

Comment: My first thought was batteries as @MichaelKaras suggested. If the batteries are low, they may just not have enough power to transmit while you're in your car driving up, while they may be good enough for resetting/testing (from much closer with no car blocking the signals).

Comment: If not batteries, can you isolate the problem a bit more? When they "stop working", do they absolutely stop working (no matter how many times you press the button and no matter distance from opener) or will they work in some situations (eg, close up) or otherwise intermittently? Do they both stop working at the exact same time (before you reset codes, obviously)? After resetting, will they work consistently even from decent distances (eg, standing out in the street)?

Answer (score 3):

What is the condition of the batteries in the remotes? Make sure that you have good fresh batteries so that a strong signal gets to the garage door opener base unit.

Also evaluate if it is possible that something has changed in the area around the garage door main unit. Have you recently placed some large metal object nearby that may affect the RF signal path from the remote to the base unit. Maybe an alumimum extension ladder or a metal storage cabinet.

Lastly is it possible that a neighbor may have a similar model opener to yours and it uses a "rolling code" security feature. Your opener could be picking up some stray signals from their opener and making yours get out of sync with your transmitter dongles.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the opener has a button battery (similar to a watch battery) that powers the memory. It may be failing. Check your manual or the manufacturers website to see if it has one.